# Interpreting data from an array java

Tags: java, arraylist, java.util.scanner

I have an assignment that requires me to take a large dataset, store it in an array, and then create methods that interpret the data in various ways. The file data I am given is in the form like so:

0  138
    0   139
    0   140
    0   141
    0   142
    0   799
    4   1
    4   10
    4   12
    4   18
etc... (it is very large)
This data is supposed to represent a social network of people, with the numbers representing individuals. Each line contains a person on the left who has 'trusted' the person on the right. I am supposed to interpret this data so that I can find all the persons a particular person trusts, how many people trust a particular person, and how to find the most trusted person. However, I am at a complete loss as to how to write these methods, and so I was wondering if you guys could help me out. Here's the code I have so far:

```
public class SocialNetwork {

static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
static void findTrusted()
{
    System.out.println("Please input person number you would like to find Trustees for");
    trustee = (scanner.next());
}


public static void main(String[] args){
    File inData = new File("dataset.txt");
    ArrayList<Integer> links = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    try
    {   
        Scanner in = new Scanner(inData);
        in.nextLine();
        in.nextLine();
        in.nextLine();
        in.nextLine();
        while (in.hasNext())
        {
            int trustee = in.nextInt();
            int trusted = in.nextInt();
            links.add(trustee);
            links.add(trusted);


        }
        in.close();
    }

    catch (FileNotFoundException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}   
}
```

As you can see, my findTrustee method has very little in it. I just don't know where to even start. I have come up with a little pseudocode to try and dissect what needs to be done:

1. prompt user for input on which person(integer) to find his/her trustees
2. search arraylist links for person(integer) inputted
3. print all persons(integers) on the right side of the lines that begin with person requested

However, I just don't quite know how to do this.

Comment: This is basically an application of graph theory: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_theory

Comment: Or maybe not, if all you want to know is information regarding the incoming and outgoing trust for one particular person, rather than also considering *transitive* trust.

Answer (score 1):

The structure `links` doesn't really help you.  It has no idea of "from" and "to". You are storing Persons as numbers, but not storing any relationships between two people.  You're really working in graph theory, and when you can you should look at reference works and Java libraries for graph theory.

So, what is a trust link? It is an object that has two people, the trustee and trusted people. Create a class for this:

```
public class Trust {
    private final int trustee;
    private final int trusted;
    public Trust(final int trustee, final int trusted) {
        this.trustee = trustee;
        this.trusted = trusted;
    }
    // Getters, equals, hashCode, toString, formatted output for humans.
}
```

Have your class `SocialNetwork` be able to create these. By the way, create a SocialNetwork instance in your main method, and stop using static for everything else.

```
public Trust createTrust(Scanner scanner) {
    int trustee = scanner.nextInt();
    int trusted = scanner.nextInt();
    return new Trust(trustee, trusted);
}
```

You might need to add exception handling and end of file handling.

Make `links` a list of `Trust` objects, and then write methods that scan that list as needed.

```
/**
    Return a list of all the people who trustee trusts.
    @param trustee A person in the system.
    @return a list of the people trustee trusts.
 */
public List<Integer> trusting(int trustee) {
    final List<Integer> trusted = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Trust link: links) {
        // Add something from link to trusted if it should.
        // This looks like homework; I'm not doing everything for you.
    }
    return trusted;
}
```

Write other methods as you need them.  Then, think about whether these data structures are efficient for this problem. Could `Map`s be better? `MultiMap`s from other libraries?  An open source graph theory library of some sort?  Perhaps you should use a database instead. Perhaps you should have a `Person` class instead of using just integers; that way you can label people with their names.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are quite a number of ways you can implement this (regardless of performance). For example, you can use HashMap, array of array (or list of lists if you really like list...)

I will give an example using list maybe, since you seem using it... (although I think this is a bit odd)

Say, you have a list holding the people on the left.

```
ArrayList<ArrayList> leftList = new ArrayList<ArrayList>();
```

For leftList,loop through it till you reach the max no. of the left column (now you may see why an array/HashMap is better...) by doing something like:

```
leftList.add(new ArrayList());
```

in each loop.

Then all you have to do now is to read the file and plug the list of trustees to rightList corresponding to the truster. E.g. I have 1 3, 1 4 and 2 3; your implementation will achieve sth like:

```
leftList.get(1).add(3) / leftList.get(1).add(4) / leftList.get(2).add(3)
```

depending which line you are reading.

With this setup, I guess you can solve those three questions quite easily? Otherwise, just look for more advice here. But make sure you think through it first!

Hope my answer gives you some ideas.